# Как сделать, так, чтоб текст в отдельном div не уходил под основной текст и фото страницы

Tags: html, css

Такая проблема, как это пофиксить?[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) поможет в вашем случае.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/736275)

Comment: @void, но ведь ссылка на сайт developer.mozilla.org, очень вероятно, будет содержать более актуальную информацию в будущем, чем этот ответ, если изменятся какие-либо браузерные API.

Answer (score 0):

Так как самого хтмл-а и CSS-а вы не предоставили, определить проблему трудно. Я думаю что flex контейнер может сделать ваш layout более структурированным и тем самым устранить нежелаемый эффект.

1. Поставьте у себя div контейнер.

```html
<div class="flex"></div>
```

2. Поместите в этот контейнер картинку и остальной текст, каждое в свой div контейнер.

```html
<div class="flex">

    <!-- 1-ый дочерной элемент flex контейнера -->
    <div>
        <img src="./image" />
    </div>

    <!-- 2-ой дочерной элемент flex контейнера -->
    <div>
        <h1>Filter by product categories</h1>
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

3. Добавьте нужный CSS.

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;

    /* Делает ряды а не колонки */
    flex-direction: column;

    /* Выравнивает элементы вертикально к вершине */
    align-content: flex-start;

    /* Выравнивает элементы горизонтально по центру */
    justify-items: center;
}
```

Результат:

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: flex-start;
    justify-items: center;
}

.flex > * {
    border: 1px solid #000f;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <div>
        <img src="https://www.cameraegg.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Nikon-D500-Sample-Images-2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Filter by product categories</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```